# Как правильно узнавать несколько значений с одного v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, select

Существует такая задача: На сайте нужно выбрать товар

```
<select name="item" v-model="select">
   <option v-for="item in items" :value="item.value">{{item.text}} ({{item.price}}$)</option>
</select>
```

```
data: {
  items: [
    {value: 1, text: "Товар 1", price: 100 },
    {value: 2, text: "Товар 2", price: 110 },
    {value: 3, text: "Товар 3", price: 120 },
  ],
},
```

Как при выборе товара узнавать цену? (Нужно ли использовать data-* и как получить к ним доступ?)

Answer (score 0):

Как пример, в селекте можно хранить индекс массива. Таким образом, сможете получить все что хотите от выбранного элемента. Например так:

```
<select name="item" v-model="select">
   <option v-for="(item, key) in items" :value="key">{{item.text}} ({{item.price}}$)</option>
</select>
<p v-if="select !== null">Price: {{items[select].price}}
```

P.S в моем примере у свойства "`select`" значение по умолчанию `null`.
Либо сделать через `watch`. При изменения значения `select`, перебрать массив и найти нужный элемент с помощью фильтрации по `value`.

Comment: Да просто событие change сделайте и передавайте туда вашу цену

Comment: watch - как по мне лучше с точки зрения производительности

Comment: что если у нас value совершенно другое, например строки? как тогда искать?

Comment: чисто перебором массива находить, то что нужно?

Comment: @Denver, да, самый простой вариант